# K means clustering and Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I need to use the `kmeans` function on a rgb image. Each element of the algorithm need to have 3 dimensions, one for each channel of the image. The number of elements will be the total amount of pixels of the image. I need to use `kmeans` on the cluster #5.

So this is what I tried:

```
img = imread('mypic.jpg');
red = img(:,:,1);
green = img(:,:,2);
blue = img(:,:,3);

kmeans(red,5)
```

I dont know if I'm doing it correctly or not. I'm having this error:

```
??? Error using ==> plus
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in ==> kmeans>distfun at 704
            D(:,i) = D(:,i) + (X(:,j) - C(i,j)).^2;

Error in ==> kmeans at 313
    D = distfun(X, C, distance, 0);

Error in ==> mysegmentation at 9
kmeans(R,2)
```

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exception, is due to the fact that `kmeans` is expecting data of type double (Thus the call to `double` in the second line below).  But you have an additional issue, in that you're not passing the proper data into kmeans.  You need to create a single numpixels x 3 matrix.  `reshape` is your friend for this stuff.  Here's an example.  Good luck.

```
img = imread('mypic.jpg');
flatImg = double(reshape(img,size(img,1)*size(img,2),size(img,3)));
idx = kmeans(flatImg,5);
imagesc(reshape(idx,size(img,1),size(img,2)));
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I needed, a numpixels x 3 matrix. Is hard for me to understand a bit the reshape funcion. That function returns a 'size(img,1)*size(img,2)' x 'size(img,3)' matrix, right? Can you explain it a bit? You are putting the 'R*G x B' on the matrix? I'm sorry but I'm quite new with image processing and I need some help with it :)

Comment: The value of img(1,1,:) is a 3 element vector holding the RGB values for the pixel at index (1,1).   The value of flatImg(1,:) is the same as the value of img(1,1,:).  Similarly, the 3 elements at img(1,2,:) are the same as the 3 elements at flatImg(2,:).  We are reorganizing the structure of the img matrix to treat the pixels as just vectors of RGB values, and ignoring their spatial relationships.

Comment: Great, I see, I'm understanding it little by little! And what if I want to join 2 more dimensions (now will be a total of 5 dimensions). One with the row number of the the pixel and the other one with the number of the column. How can I change that 'flatImg' reshape? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code already handles that issue size(img,3) handles 5 channel images, or 30 channel images....

Comment: How can I select the row #3 of the matrix? I know how to get the elements of row #3 (img(3,:)). But I dont know how can I put as a input the row number. I'm getting this error when I add something to the reshape function: "To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change."

Comment: You need to use the command that I have above.  If you want to select the blue channel of an RGB image (for example) you do the following:  img(:,:,3) but you shouldn't be doing anything like that for kmeans.

Answer (score 1):

Try `img = double(imread('mypic.jpg'))/255.;`

Answer (score 0):

```
I1= imread('d:\flowers.jpg');
I2=rgb2gray(I1);

I=double(I2);
figure
subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(I1)
subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(I2)
g=kmeans(I(:),4);
J = reshape(g,size(I));
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(J,[])
```